# c# DataTable Linq Group by Multiple column sum int and timespan

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable, linq-to-entities

I want to sum of all Volume & TotalTimes Column after Group BY from DataTable Alias as Temp_DT. Remember Volume & All TotalTimes Column may have null or blank value.
Can anyone help me to get the code through **Linq Method**

Sample Temp_DT:

[image]

Result should be in this format
[image]

I have tried the below code, but  Temp_DT result is Null.

```
var Temp_DT = tempdt.AsEnumerable().Select(x =>
                    new
                    {
                        UID = x.Field<string>("UID"),
                        EMPNAME = x.Field<string>("Emp Name"),
                        EMPROLE = x.Field<string>("Role"),
                        SUPID = x.Field<string>("Sup ID"),
                        SUPNAME = x.Field<string>("Sup Name"),
                        DESIGNATION = x.Field<string>("Designation"),
                        VOLUME = x.Field<int>("Volume"),
                        LOGINTIME = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Login Time"),
                        BREAKTIME = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Break Time"),
                        HANDLETIME = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Handle Time"),
                        ACTIVETIME = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Active Time"),
                        HOLDTIME = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Hold Time"),
                        ACWTIME = x.Field<TimeSpan>("ACW"),
                        IDLETIME = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Idle"),
                        PRODUCTIVE = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Productive"),
                        NONPRODUCTIVE = x.Field<TimeSpan>("Non Productive"),
                        USERERROR = x.Field<TimeSpan>("User Error Time")
                    }).GroupBy(s => new { s.UID, s.EMPNAME, s.EMPROLE, s.SUPID, s.SUPNAME, s.DESIGNATION })
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        g.Key.UID,
                        g.Key.EMPNAME,
                        g.Key.EMPROLE,
                        g.Key.SUPID,
                        g.Key.SUPNAME,
                        g.Key.DESIGNATION,
                        VOLUME = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt16(x.VOLUME)),
                        LOGINTIME = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.LOGINTIME.Ticks)),
                        BREAKTIME = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.BREAKTIME.Ticks)),
                        HANDLETIME = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.HANDLETIME.Ticks)),
                        ACTIVETIME = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.ACTIVETIME.Ticks)),
                        HOLDTIME = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.HOLDTIME.Ticks)),
                        ACWTIME = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.ACWTIME.Ticks)),
                        IDLETIME = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.IDLETIME.Ticks)),
                        PRODUCTIVE = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.PRODUCTIVE.Ticks)),
                        NONPRODUCTIVE = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.NONPRODUCTIVE.Ticks)),
                        USERERROR = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.USERERROR.Ticks)),
                    });
```

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far

Comment: Code added, which i tried but unable to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Parse the `TimeSpan` and `Sum` by using `Ticks`, like below.

```
var Temp_DT = tempdt.AsEnumerable().Select(x =>
                    new
                    {
                        UID = x["UID"],
                        EMPNAME = x["Emp Name"],
                        EMPROLE = x["Role"],
                        SUPID = x["Sup ID"],
                        SUPNAME = x["Sup Name"],
                        DESIGNATION = x["Designation"],
                        VOLUME = x["Volume"],
                        ERRORTIME = x["Error_Time"],                            
                        ACWTIME = x["ACW"],
                        BREAKTIME = x["Break Time"],
                        IDLETIME = x["Idle"],
                        NONPRODUCTIVE = x["Non Productive"],
                    }).GroupBy(s => new { s.UID, s.EMPNAME, s.EMPROLE, s.SUPID, s.SUPNAME, s.DESIGNATION })
                    .Select(g => {
                      var grouped = g.ToList();
                      return new
                      {
                          UID = g.Key.UID,
                          EMPNAME = g.Key.EMPNAME,
                          EMPROLE = g.Key.EMPROLE,
                          SUPID = g.Key.SUPID,
                          SUPNAME = g.Key.SUPNAME,
                          DESIGNATION = g.Key.DESIGNATION,
                          VOLUME = grouped.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt16(x.VOLUME)),
                          Error_Time = new TimeSpan(grouped.Select(x => ConvertTimeSpan(x.ERRORTIME.ToString())).ToList().Sum(r=> r.Ticks)),
                          ACW = new TimeSpan(grouped.Select(x => ConvertTimeSpan(x.ACWTIME.ToString())).ToList().Sum(r=> r.Ticks)),
                          Break = new TimeSpan(grouped.Select(x => ConvertTimeSpan(x.BREAKTIME.ToString())).ToList().Sum(r=> r.Ticks)),
                          Idle = new TimeSpan(grouped.Select(x => ConvertTimeSpan(x.IDLETIME.ToString())).ToList().Sum(r=> r.Ticks)),
                          NonProductive = new TimeSpan(grouped.Select(x => ConvertTimeSpan(x.NONPRODUCTIVE.ToString())).ToList().Sum(r=> r.Ticks))
                      };
                    }).ToList();
```

The Conversion method is,

```
private static TimeSpan ConvertTimeSpan(string str)
{
   TimeSpan outputValue; 
   TimeSpan.TryParse(str, out outputValue);

   return outputValue;
}
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RhGWa) with sample data.

Comment: No Error .. But TimeSpan doesn't add its only picking up the first value.

Comment: @Sarfaraz78615 give more input, as the given sample data with Fiddle, it is working as expected.